# Question about WooCommerce Subscription

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have installed the Woocommerce plugin but I can't figure out how to get the actual monthly amount to show up on receipts.
The plugin seems to add all one-time charges and show them as a part of the monthly subscription[image: subscription receipt image]

My question is how do I get the one-time charges to separate from the recurring charges on the receipt?
In this case it should only show the car plus taxes as the monthly and the delivery charge and deposit as a one-time charge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to review the docs for WooCommerce Subscriptions directly on this. From the screenshot, it looks like you're adding the one-time fee to the product rather than the cart checkout.  There's a section in the Subscription Docs that talks specifically about the recurring fees aspect and what code to change.

Unfortunately, the forums here are for WordPress itself and not the WooCommerce plugin, so you'll want to check their docs and support team directly.